# VHDL deactivate component properly

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I want to deactivate components in my FPGA design properly and try it either with an Enable-Output in the component, that gets into an AND with the clock driving the component itself or with

```
if(rising_edge(clk) AND Enable = 1) then
...
```

[image: TopLevel BDF]

[image: RTL Viewer both activated]

In my RTL-Viewer it seems like it deactivates properly and the CLK goes through another AND gate, which should induce some latency if I keep the component activated.

[image: RTL Viewer internal AND deactivated]

In the technology map viewer it seems like the compiler isn't caring at all about the deactivation method, doesn't matter which one I deactivate, there's always no component and always no AND in front of the clock

[image: Technology Map internal AND deactivated]

So my guess is, both methods are equally useful?

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand what you're asking. I would however recommend extreme caution when gating clocks. I would read the instructions for your FPGA and follow their recommendations exactly.

Comment: Look at the top level BDF, I want to know if I can deactivate components one or the other way. Afaik the compiler should remove the AND in front of the clock input anyway (cause it's alway 1 or 0) and just wanted to have that confirmed.

Comment: Clock Gating is a hardware question, not a coding question. In FPGAs clock gating is basically not recommended. All registers in an FPGA have a clock enable input.

Comment: It's not meant to work at runtime, this is for compiling different contents from one project to control size and functions of the final application. Lets say I have some applications with the same base (PLLs, filters, etc.) but different hardware ICs to grab my data. I want to deactivate some Interfaces and activate others and want to evaluate the best method. But it seems both are equal, the compiler kills off the component in both ways without any signs of it left in the final application.